# [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'image' is not present]

Tags: java, spring-boot, flutter, dart, multipart

I try to send an image with some attributes from flutter to spring boot endpoint, but spring boot not received the image at all and it gives me this error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'image' is not present]
```

here is my code:

### Spring boot

```
@PostMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<UsersEntity> createNewUser(@RequestParam(value = "image") MultipartFile image, UsersEntity user) {
    UsersEntity response = userService.createUser(user, image);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

### Flutter

```
var postUri = Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/v1");
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
request.fields['fName'] = firstNameController.text;
request.fields['lName'] = lastNameController.text;
if(image != null) {
  request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      'image', image!, contentType: MediaType.parse('multipart/form-data')));
}

Map<String, String> headers = {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale",
  "content-type": "application/json"};
request.headers.addAll(headers);

request.send().then((response) {
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Success!");
  } else {
    print('Error!');
  }
});
```

My service work very well with Postman, any idea how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Credit to this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37311#issuecomment-516967285

I just add `filename` and every thing work fine:

```
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'image', image!, 
    contentType: MediaType.parse('multipart/form-data'), 
    filename: 'test.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var uri = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/services/selfemployment/check-confirmation-code');
  var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

   request.headers.addAll(baseHeader);
   request.fields['example'] = example;
   request.fields['image'] = image;
   http.Response response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
   print('Uploaded! ${response.body} ++ ${response.statusCode}');
```